# How to form SP initiated URL for openam/saml2 with ADFS?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, openam

I tried various ways as explained in http://openam.forgerock.org/ & in stackoverflow, but getting different errors (Mentioned below). Any help on what I am missing is highly appreciated.

SP - https://sp.abc.xyz.com
IDP - https://adfs.xyz.com/adfs/

URL:
https://sp.abc.xyz.com/OpenAM/spssoinit?idpEntityID=https://adfs.xyz.com/adfs/
ERROR:

> HTTP Status 400 - Service Provider ID is null.

URL:
https://sp.abc.xyz.com/OpenAM/spssoinit?metaAlias=/sp&idpEntityID=https://adfs.xyz.com/adfs/
ERROR:

> HTTP Status 400 - Error processing AuthnRequest. Error retrieving meta
>   data.

Thanks
Aravind

Comment: Did you get the second error at the SP or the IdP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was - my IDP forces to use only URN in idpEntityID. The issue is solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

SP and IDP URLs should be something like this

SP: 
https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml
entityID = https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml/metadata/alias/defaultAlias

IDP:
https://sts.xyp.com/adfs/ls

entityID = http://sts.enel.com/adfs/services/trust